# ansible template with if condition inventory name

Tags: templates, ansible

Actually I try to create network configs for a network bridge. For this I have the following in group_vars.

```
---
backbone_ip:
- name: server2
  ipv4: 111.111.111.2/24
  ipv6: 2001:111:111:1::2/64
- name: server3
  ipv4: 111.111.111.3/24
  ipv6: 2001:111:111:1::3/64
- name: server5
  ipv4: 111.111.111.5/24
  ipv6: 2001:111:111:1::5/64
```

With the template Module I write the config. The template:

```
auto br-{{ bridge_network }}
iface br-{{ bridge_network }} inet static
{% for server in backbone_ip %}
{% if server.name in hostvars[host].inventory_hostname %}
        address {{ server.ipv4 }}
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

iface br-{{ bridge_network }} inet6 static
        address {{ server.ipv6 }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now my problem is that i want only write the lines if server.name is the inventory name of the server ansible actually connected to.

hostvars[host].inventory_hostname seems to be wrong.
shouĺd a change in to = or how is the syntax?

Thanks
pr0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is a wrong structure for this use-case. Change it to a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
  backbone_dict:
    server2:
      ipv4: 111.111.111.2/24
      ipv6: 2001:111:111:1::2/64
    server3:
      ipv4: 111.111.111.3/24
      ipv6: 2001:111:111:1::3/64
    server5:
      ipv4: 111.111.111.5/24
      ipv6: 2001:111:111:1::5/64
```

Then addressing of the attributes is trivial, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ backbone_dict[inventory_hostname].ipv4 }}"
```

If you can't change the structure of the data convert it first, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        backbone_dict: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(backbone_ip)) }}"
      vars:
        _keys: "{{ backbone_ip|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes its so simple. It works and its much easier.

But I have a little problem. I have the variable {{ bridge_network }}. How can I use this with the backbone_dict in an template.

backbone should be {{ bridge_network }}
This doenst work
{{ {{bridge_network }}_dict[inventory_hostname].ipv4 }}

Comment: IIUC, the problem is indirect referencing of a variable (not included in the question). See [Create Variable From Ansible Facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957578/create-variable-from-ansible-facts/). Open a new question if this is not what you want. In fact, you shouldn't comment on problems not related to this question and answer. In this case, always open a new question if you can't find an answer.